Not able to persist keyboard on the mobile screen while tapping outside or scrolling the page in flutter
In my flutter PWA (app is being viewed from a mobile browser), i want to NOT dismiss the keyboard.
Every time I tap outside or scroll the screen to see other details on the page, in the form, it dismisses.
Even if the input field loses focus - i want to keep the keyboard visible on the screen.
I tried to add GestureDetector, NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>, TapRegion
But I'm only able to request focus again and I'm not able to retain it.
On trying FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_model.textFieldFocusNode) ->Keyboard closes and then opens again - which gives a bad user experience.
How to prevent keyboard from closing unless a certain condition is true.
Is this possible at all?
Things I have tried (and didn't work):

In GestureDetector

behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
onTap: () {
    // Either requesting focus again
    if (!canLoseFocus) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_model.textFieldFocusNode);
    }

    // Or leaving the onTap function empty to not dismiss the keyboard
},


In NotificationListener

NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
        if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
            // Requesting focus again if it is lost
            if (!canLoseFocus) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_model.textFieldFocusNode);
            }
        }
        return true; // Consume scroll notifications to prevent focus loss
    },


Also, wrapped widgets TapRegion to prevent input field from losing focus

This is the code for my text input field
TextFormField(
    controller: _model.textController,
    focusNode: _model.textFieldFocusNode,
    autofocus: false,
    obscureText: false,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).labelMedium.override(
            fontSize: AppFontSizes.medium/textScaleFac,
            color: AppColors.textLightLabel,
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            letterSpacing: 0,
        ),
        hintText: 'Enter Answer Here',
        hintStyle: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).labelMedium.override(
            color: AppColors.textLightLabel,
            fontSize: AppFontSizes.medium,
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            letterSpacing: 0,
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: AppColors.inputDarkBorder,
                width: 1,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: AppColors.inputDarkBorder,
                width: 1,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
    ),
    style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyMedium.override(
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
        fontSize: 14,
        color: Colors.white,
        letterSpacing: 0,
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    maxLines: 6,
    validator: _model.textControllerValidator.asValidator(context),
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done, // Shows the "Done" button on the keyboard
    onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
        setState(() {
            canLoseFocus = true;
        });
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        _model.textFieldFocusNode?.unfocus();
    },
),


Dear Use FocusNode to make the Next Field Focused on Submit of previous One
you can practice this just like this
class MyFormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFormWidgetState createState() => _MyFormWidgetState();
}

class _MyFormWidgetState extends State<MyFormWidget> {
  FocusNode _textFieldFocusNode;
  bool canLoseFocus = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _textFieldFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!_textFieldFocusNode.hasFocus && !canLoseFocus) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textFieldFocusNode);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textFieldFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (!canLoseFocus) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textFieldFocusNode);
        }
      },
      child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
          if (!canLoseFocus) {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textFieldFocusNode);
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: TextEditingController(),
          focusNode: _textFieldFocusNode,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter Answer Here',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
          maxLines: 6,
          onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
            setState(() {
              canLoseFocus = true;
            });
            _textFieldFocusNode.unfocus();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Hey @Shoua, I'm using flutterflow input fields for the implementation. Also, the issue is not with bringing other fields into focus (in my case i have only 1 input text field). The issue is - i want to allow users to scroll the page while not losing focus (or atleast not dismissing the keyboard)

try this updated version of code, hope it'll help you

Thanks for trying but as I've mentioned, the requestFocus() implementation did not work for be because even if we're able to get focus again - the focus is lost once before that - which triggers keyboard to close. Keyboard closing and opening is not a good user experience.

have you tried ?, asking for my GK

UI Qammar, yes i have tried that. It doesn't work as expected. Also it works better for android devices that it does on ios.

so it worked but not on an specific device hah fine

No it doesn't work @Shoua
